# how to add class to {% block content %} in twig

Tags: 8, theming, blocks

Here goes my drupal 8 code, so basically `block.html.twig` is extended to `block--mytheme-sitebranding.html.twig`.

Now I want to add a class to this:

```
{% block content %}

  {% if site_logo %}

    <a href="{{ path('<front>') }}" title="{{ 'Home'|t }}" rel="home">
      <img src="{{ site_logo }}" alt="{{ 'Home'|t }}" />
    </a>

  {% endif %}
  {% if site_name %}

    <a href="{{ path('<front>') }}" title="{{ 'Home'|t }}" rel="home">{{ site_name }}</a>

  {% endif %}
  {{ site_slogan }}

 {% endblock %}
```

How can I add a class to `{% block content %}` in Twig for `block--mytheme-sitebranding.html.twig`?

Comment: `{% block %}` is a Twig tag, not an HTML tag, so you can't add a class to it.

Comment: `block` does not mean block in the sense that is a Drupal block. Different terminology. Check the Twig docs.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [block_class](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_class) module can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In your block.html.twig file ensure you have a containing div, and that "attributes" are being printed. This will give your block an ID of the block name, and typically the class "contextual-region".

If you need a class specific to this block, you can add the block ID as a class like so:

block.html.twig:

```
{%
    set extraBlockClasses = attributes.id | clean_class
%}

<div {{ attributes.addClass(extraBlockClasses) }}>
    {% block content %}
        {{ content }}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

block--override.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'block.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    {{ content }}
{% endblock %}
```

Unfortunately, "{% block content %}" is not a "thing" to which you may add a class. Use descendent CSS selectors from your block class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a class to `{% block content %}` – but you can add a class to the wrapping element.

Instead of the line `{% extends 'block.html.twig' %}` you can delete all the content of your template `block--mytheme-sitebranding.html.twig` and replace it with the content of the original template `block.html.twig`.

Then alter the elements inside of `{% block content %}` as you like – for example:

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'MY-NEW-CLASS',
  ]
%}
<div{{attributes.addClass(classes)}}>
  {{ title_prefix }}
  {{ title_suffix }}

  {% block content %}

  {% if site_logo %}

    <a href="{{ path('<front>') }}" title="{{ 'Home'|t }}" rel="home">
      <img src="{{ site_logo }}" alt="{{ 'Home'|t }}"/>
    </a>

  {% endif %}
  {% if site_name %}

  <a href="{{ path('<front>') }}" title="{{ 'Home'|t }}" rel="home">{{ site_name }}</a>

  {% endif %}
  {{ site_slogan }}

  {% endblock %}
</div>
```